# Counting the elements in a local array

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I have a `double x[12]` which has no elements in it. When the user is prompted, he/she enters a number, which is stored in `x`.

I want the program to first check if `x` is empty and if it is, put the user's input in `x[0]` or if it isn't, put the user's input in the next free index.

I had done this:

```
...

double x[12];

void AddPayment(double Amount)
{
    int i = sizeof(x);

    x[i] = Amount;
}
```

Is it that sizeof() doesn't work with arrays, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `sizeof` is applied to an array, it does not tell you how much data the array holds; it tells you how much data the array *could* hold. The fact that you did not specify any data to put into your `double x[12]` has no influence on the size of the array. Therefore, `sizeof` would return the number of bytes required on your system to hold an array of twelve `double`s.

If you would like to keep a count of how many items among 12 have been assigned, add a separate variable for it. Initialize it to zero, and use it to keep track of how many items have been inserted:

```
size_t x_count = 0;
double x[12];
void AddPayment(double Amount) {
    if (x_count == 12) {
        // Error; we cannot add more than 12 items.
        // Tell the user what's going on and quit,
        // or handle the error in some other way.
        cerr << "Cannot add more than 12 elements to x[]" << endl;
        return;
    }
    x[x_count++] = Amount;
}
```

Comment: An array always holds the same amount of data. There is no difference between "does hold" and "could hold".

Comment: @ChristianHackl From the point of view of a compiler or a CPU, there is no difference. From the point of view of a program, there's lots of difference. For example, when `x_count` in the program above is set to 6, the array holds some data of interest in the initial 6 elements; the remaining 6 elements hold junk, not data.

Comment: `x_count` is just a specific interpretation of the 6 elements. It's still 6 elements we are dealing with. They hold junk data (more specifically, reading from them is undefined behaviour), but there are 6 of them. A raw array has no concept of emptiness. Something like `x[0]` is malformed.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I would rather not turn this into a hair splitting exercise, if it is OK with you.

Comment: It's not a hair-splitting exercise, because it's important that the OP understands the difference between fixed-size and variable-size containers.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Hair-splitting is in the eye of the beholder. I think OP already understands what's necessary to complete the problem at hand. I am also certain that the answer has cleared OP's confusion about the way the `sizeof` operator works with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Whether x[12] has values or not, it will always have a size of 12 * sizeof(double).

So using the sizeof() operator is not a good way to accomplish your aim.

A best thing to do would be initialize x[12] with a value that the user cannot enter, say 0, and test for the first available location in the array that has a zero to enter that value.

```
double x[12] = { 0 };

void AddPayment(double Amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (x[i] == 0) {
            x[i] = Amount;
            break;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, it is an operator.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a `double x[12]` which has no elements in it.

That's a misconception. `double x[12];` creates 12 `double` elements, leaving their values in an undefined status. So you have 12 uninitialised elements. That's quite different from having *no* elements.

*(The misconception would become even clearer if you had, for example, an array of type `std::string`. Unlike `double`, `std::string` is always initialised to a defined value, an empty string. So `std::string x[12]` would definitely be 12 strings, not an empty array.)*

> When the user is prompted, he/she enters a number, which is stored in
>   `x`.
>
> I want the program to first check if `x` is empty and if it is, put the
>   user's input in `x[0]` or if it isn't, put the user's input in the next
>   free index.

I'm really surprised that nobody has suggested this, but an array is the wrong tool for what you are trying to accomplish. You need a container which can **grow**. You need `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<double> x; // starts off empty

void AddPayment(double Amount)
{
    x.push_back(Amount); // grows by 1 element
}
```

`std::vector` also has a `size()` member function to tell you the current number of elements. No more `sizeof` needed.